# Table in C# with conditional cell values

Tags: c#, random, grid

I need help to generate the following table in .txt file using C#

[image]

For each cell in the table, a random number will be generated between 0 and 100 (inclusive). If the number is between 5 and 95, the cell will have a " * ", else it will be a blank cell.

Comment: Hover over those tags and read the pop up text.

Comment: My Bad plutonix, pretty new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char[] table = new char[9];
for(int i =0;i<table.Length;i++)
{
  int nbr =new Random().Next(0,100);//you can add the seed inside random constructor
  if( nbr<5 || nbr >95)
   table[i] = '*';
  else
   table[i] = ' ';
}
```

**For the text file use this method**

> add using System.IO; so you use the StreamWriter

```
void WriteToTxt(string[] table,string fileName)
{
 StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(fileName);
 int column=1;
 writer.WriteLine(" _________");
 for(int i =0;i<table.Length;i++)
 {
   writer.WriteLine("|"+table[i]+" |");
   column++;
   if(column == 3)
   {
    column =1;
    writer.WriteLine("|__|__|__|");
   }
 }
 writer.Close();
}
```

play with the spaces to make the size you want hope it helps if so please mark this as the answer :)
have a nice day !

Comment: Thanks Th3Wolf. How do I write this to a txt file along with the table borders. 
Can this be achieved without the GridView

Comment: You're welcome Kinjal :)

Comment: wait a moment i'll update the answer and add the code to write a text file ;)

Comment: @KinjalMaruShah take a look now at the answer

Comment: Thanks much @Th3Wolf. I am working on a project and didn't know where to start. Would it be too much to share the project and get some thoughts?

Comment: You're welcome again

Comment: you can contact me any time 

anas.elmoutaouakil@gmail.com

Comment: shooting an email